Im trying to create a new expo app but get hit with the same error everytime (Note: Yarn did work)
Every time i try to create a new Expo app on my macbook i keep getting the same error, I've changed npm versions tried uninstalling all my versions and reinstalling them, switched to the lts etc but nothing seems to work.
`npx create-expo-app ple2 --template blank
✖ Something went wrong in downloading and extracting the project files: Could not parse JSON returned from "npm pack expo-template-blank@latest --dry-run".
expo-template-blank-51.0.27.tgz
Error: Unexpected token 'e', "expo-templ"... is not valid JSON
Error: Could not parse JSON returned from "npm pack expo-template-blank@latest --dry-run".
expo-template-blank-51.0.27.tgz
Error: Unexpected token 'e', "expo-templ"... is not valid JSON
`
I've really tried everything but nothing helps, I switched to yarn instead and it seemed to work that way, but i still want to fix this issue, and not keep depending on yarn

What is your node version ?

im currently using the lts version but ive tried switching between different versions nothing seemed to work ive uninstalled versions and reinstalled them cleared cache but nothing seems to help yarn does work but the rest just doesnt
